# rich:picklist don't call setter

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, picklist

I want  to call the setter of the selected list on the right once I Pick an Item it's not the case when  is in the pop up. the setter is called when the pop up is closed.
and it works on normal page.
I have tried  with immediate="true" but no result
I use JSF and richFace 3.x
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your description is not sufficient, show your code.

Comment: Try putting the an ajax tag within the selectonemenu tags.